# Watching for live change of value with Jquery

Tags: jquery, live, watch

I am working on a script that counts the value in a div and based on the value different classes and text are added to an other div. The value is the amount of items in stock.

Basically if value is =0 add class .out and change text to "Out of stock", if the value is <5 add class .few-left and text "Less than 5 left!" and if the >5 add class .in-stock and text "In stock!

Though there is a catch, the value might change without page-load due to multiple variations of the same article. Therefore one article might have the value 4 and the other value 10 and the third 0 and is out of stock and this changes on hovering thumbnails of the variations much like these variations are listed: http://www.feelunique.com/p/Bare-Escentuals-id-SPF15-Matte-Foundation-Lockable-Sifter-6g

Is it possible to track the changes of the value "live" so to speak. I want it to watch that value and if it goes over/under the different break-points i want the class to be replaced by the new class.

Example of how the html would look in three different scenarios

```
<div class="stock-value">4</div>
<div class="stock-message few-left">Less than 5 left!</div>

<div class="stock-value">9</div>
<div class="stock-message in-stock">In stock!/div>

<div class="stock-value">0</div>
<div class="stock-message in-stock">Out of stock/div>
```

I tried something like this:

```
jQuery('.stock-wrap').each(function() {
    var Saldo = jQuery('.stock-value').val();
    if(Saldo <= 5){
        jQuery('.stock-message').text('Less than 5 left!');
        jQuery('.stock-message').addClass('few-left');
        }
    });
```

Though this does not watch for change and I am afraid my jQuery skills does not hande this level just yet.

Thank you in advance for any kind of help!

Best
Rickard

Comment: How does the value change in the first place? Is there another piece of Javascript doing that?

Comment: Will need CSS styles to come back to proper look and feel. Would suggest using a text field to store the stock-value, you can then listen to the onchange event on this field and update the stock-message div accordingly

Comment: The value change is coming from the database without any javascript.